# Splitting string having special characters, words, numbers and URL

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a .txt file which contains:

```
"'the url address i checked is: https://www.google.com/ for 2times and it's awesome!."
```

After parsing, the expected output should be:

```
['"',"'",'the','url','address','i','checked','is',':','https://www.google.com/','for','2','times','and',"it's",'awesome','!','.','"']
```

How do I split this list to get the output using the `re` module.

I came up with this pattern:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+|[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z']*|[^\w\s]")
```

but this is also splitting my URL.
Can any one please help?

Comment: Looks like you want a chunker - check out NLTK. Also, why the leading and trailing empty strings?

Comment: Is it okay, in this problem to make a special rule for URLs?

Comment: Just add another alternation with a url pattern.

Comment: Ya.. I would want to keep url's as it is (without splitting)

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a url regex from somewhere and make it first in the alternations.
An example only -

```
   #  (?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?|\d+|[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z']*|[^\w\s]


   (?! mailto: )
   (?:
        (?: https? | ftp )
        ://
   )?
   (?:
        \S+ 
        (?: : \S* )?
        @
   )?
   (?:
        (?:
             (?:
                  [1-9] \d? 
               |  1 \d\d 
               |  2 [01] \d 
               |  22 [0-3] 
             )
             (?:
                  \.
                  (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
             ){2}
             (?:
                  \.
                  (?:
                       [1-9] \d? 
                    |  1 \d\d 
                    |  2 [0-4] \d 
                    |  25 [0-4] 
                  )
             )
          |  (?:
                  (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                  [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
             )
             (?:
                  \.
                  (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
                  [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
             )*
             (?:
                  \.
                  (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )
             )
        )
     |  localhost
   )
   (?: : \d{2,5} )?
   (?: / [^\s]* )?
|  \d+ 
|  [a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z']* 
|  [^\w\s]
```

Outputs:

```
 ['"',"'",'the','url','address','i','checked','is',':','https://www.google.com/','for','2','times','and',"it's",'awesome','!','.','"']
```